# I am struggling to get Nginx work as expected on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, server, nginx

I am trying to deploy my NodeJS server using Ubuntu Server and Nginx.
I created a file called `mohserver` in the following directory: `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and added the following configuration inside it:

```
upstream mohserver {
    # Nodejs app upstream
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    keepalive 64;
}

# Server on port 80
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domainName;
    root /home/behrouz/mohserver;

    location / {
        # Proxy_pass configuration
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_pass http://domainName/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 240s;
    }
}
```

And I executed the following commands:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mohserver /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

systemctl start nginx
systemctl enable nginx
```

I also pointed my domain to my public ip address and when I execute: `ping myDomainName` I can see in the command line that the domain name is pointed to my public address.

But when I try to open "http://myDomainName" doesn't work. it doesn't even return `404 not found`

What am I missing here?

Comment: What error is returned in the browser? Also, can you see that a request is coming through in `/var/log/nginx`?

Comment: @MattO. no error is returned in the browser. Its like I am entering a domain that doesn't actually exists or hosted anywhere. And when I try to "cat error.log" nothing is printed.

Comment: When did you register your domain name? As it is working via ip, nginx is up and working. It takes 24 hours for new domain names to propagate.

Comment: @Panther 3 to 4 days ago. My server file is located in "/home/behrouz/". Is it okay to put it anywhere? as long as I am specifying it in the nginx conf file? or it must be located in specific folder like how the conf files are located in "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled"?

Comment: I can't even ping my public IP Address

Comment: If you can't ping your ip address or domain that suggests a routing problem or firewall. You can tats nginx form the server with a command line browser such as links or wget `wget localhost`